# How to get pictures or inline shapes from clipboard right before pasting?

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

i've got a problem with my vba application.

I want to know if it's possible to detect and remove pictures from what I've copied in word right before pasting it in a richtextbox or ink-edit component?

My approach is :

- I copy what I need in word (text, picture, etc.)
- I paste it on my userform using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>V</kbd> action
- And at this point, I want to remove the picture from the clipboard but keep the text

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove before or after pasting? If after, check my answer below.

Comment: I want to remove before pasting, also CutCopyMode is a excel method huh ?

Comment: I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As
Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub EmptyClip()
OpenClipboard (0&)
EmptyClipboard
CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: I got this, now how to only remove the picture from the clipboard ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want to keep the text but not the pictures in the clipboard

Comment: Do you copy them together, or one after another?

Comment: I copy them together.

Comment: There's a workaround way. You can copy the clipboard to a dataobject. Then delete the pictures from the dataobject and put back in clipboard.

Comment: I'll take a look then Thanks, i'll come back later if I find a solution to my issue.